# Best practices to host Flask app in IIS with domain name

Tags: flask, iis, self-hosting

I have a `flask` app developed (with `SQL Server` db) which runs behind a corporate firewall locally. Now we need other users outside our local network to access this web app. Since I am using SQL Server (with Linked Server option) to connect to other local db in network (because we do not have API), I am looking to host the web app in `IIS` itself (using [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8)). Please advise:

1. Is it safe to host using `IIS`? Any best practices to be followed to safeguard our local network, in case any penetration. Can I run the web server in Virtual Machine? Will it make it safer?
2. I also want to buy a domain name and associate with my web server IP address which will change frequently - any vendor suggestion where I can dynamically update when IP of my web server changes.

I am looking to learn the best practices to host flask web app locally using IIS with a domain name.
Thanks for your inputs!

Comment: Following the end of Python on Azure App Service (Windows) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2019 you really don't want to host any Python web apps on IIS, do you? Those tutorials over the internet are simply out-of-date.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow the below steps to host the flask app on iis:

First, you need to install the python,wfastcgi, and flask at your server.

Download the python from the below link:

https://www.python.org/downloads/

note: if possible please use the python version above 3.6.

after installing python install the wfastcgi.run the command prompt as administrator and run the below command:

```
pip install wfastcgi

wfastcgi-enable
```

below is my flask example:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello from FastCGI via IIS!"
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

after creating an application to run it use the below command:

```
python app.py
```

now enable the cgi feature of iis:

[image]

- open iis.right-click on the server name and select add site.

[image]

- enter the site name physical path and the site binding.
- after adding the site select the site name and select the handler mapping feature from the middle pane.

[image]

- Click “Add Module Mapping” from the action pane.

[image]

- executable path value:

C:\Python37-32\python.exe|C:\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py

[image]

- Click “Request Restrictions”. Make sure “Invoke handler only if the request is mapped to:” checkbox is unchecked:

[image]

- Click “Yes” here:

[image]

- now go back and select the application setting feature.

[image]

- click add from the action pane.

[image]

- Set the PYTHONPATH variable(which is your site folder path):

[image]

- And the WSGI_HANDLER (my Flask app is named app.py so the value is app.app — if yours is named site.py it would be site.app or similar):

[image]

Click OK and browse to your site.

[image]

if you want to configure the domain name with your site you need to set the site binding as below:

[image]

and bind the IP and domain name in hostile which is located at "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

IP hostname

Note: this only works locally. if you want to set the domain for internet users you need to buy the domain name and public IP and bind the IP with the domain name.

To access the SQL server iis user does not have enough permission you need to configure the use which has enough permission to access the SQL server with iis application pool.

- open iis mnager-> select application pool
- select advance setting from the action pane.
- in identity check the custom radio button and enter username and password.

[image]

Note: Make sure you assign the iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the site and python folder.

For more detail you could refer below links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019

https://forums.iis.net/post/2159167.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion..really appreciate it.. Actually I am looking for best practices to be implemented in IIS to secure my web app (and ultimately our office network) from any unwanted breach.

Comment: @jest for your first quest you can host your site in iis. if you just want to use locally then you can set some restrictions for specific users or groups that can only access the site and deny other users. use https with a certificate. and for the second question when you bind the domain name ane want to use publically you also need to buy the public IP address and bind the domain with public IP. let me know if you still have any questions.

Comment: This is an outdated solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2022#configure-the-httpplatform-handler