# Flask Permission Error when deployed to IIS

Tags: python, flask, iis, fastcgi, windows-server

I deployed a flask app to IIS using FastCGI and WSGI Handler. The steps that I have followed are

1. Created a virtual environment for Python and installed all packages including wfastCGI.
2. Set the Handler mappings and included the FastCGI settings.
3. Assigned the necessary permissions for the folders by adding IIS_IUSRS and IUSR.

Below is the medium link that I followed in terms of the steps.
https://medium.com/@dpralay07/deploy-a-python-flask-application-in-iis-server-and-run-on-machine-ip-address-ddb81df8edf3

The folder structure for the code is as shown below with (checkin_env) being the virtual environment.

[image: FolderStructure]

[image: checkFlask]

Fast CGI settings are shown as below with WSGI Handler being `checkFlask.app`

[image]

The web.config file which was generated is here.
[image]

When I tried running on Ports 80, 5000 I received a permission error related to System32 which I am totally confused and unsure about. Any thoughts or inputs are highly appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Error Received]

Comment: could you please share your web.config file? have you installed python for all users or specific user? make sure have assigned the iis user permission to the python folder. you could refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64423237/best-practices-to-host-flask-app-in-iis-with-domain-name/64437982#64437982 for more detail.

Comment: Yes I have assigned permissions for the entire folder of Checkin which already has the virtual env and python exe in it. Added webconfig as per your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with some libraries inside the `checkFlask.py` file which included `IPython.display`. Code worked fine after removing those libraries. Marking this as resolved for now. Here is a reference link for the solution I found. https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/are-wfastcgi-python-api-compatible/m-p/76578#M6215

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the below steps to run the flask app from the virtual environment:

1)Install python on your machine:

Note: Use python version above 3.6.

at the time of installation you have to remember the below things:

select customize the installation and add python to the path.

[image]

in advance setting you have selected for all users and installed at c drive:

[image]

2)Create and Configure a Python Virtual Environment for Your Application:

-Open a Command Prompt.

-Navigate to the root of the C: drive: cd C:\

-Create a new directory in which to store your virtual environments:
mkdir virtualenvs

-Navigate to the newly created virtualenvs directory:
cd virtualenvs

-Create a new virtual environment. python -m venv test

3)Activate the Virtual Environment and Upgrade pip:

-Open a Command Prompt

-Navigate to the virtual environment’s directory:

```
cd C:\virtualenvs\test
```

-Activate the virtual environment:

```
Scripts\activate.bat
```

-At this point you will see (test) at the beginning of the command prompt, indicating the virtual environment is active:

[image]

-run the below command to install pip and wfastcgi:

```
python -m pip install — upgrade pip
pip install wfastcgi
```

4)install flask:

```
pip install flask
```

5)create a site in iis:

-Create a new site in IIS and set the folder path of your flask application:

[image]

6)Configure handle mapping for site:

-Select your site, Double click “Handler Mappings”

[image]

-Click “Add Module Mapping”

[image]

-Click “Request Restrictions”. Make sure “Invoke handler only if request is mapped to:” checkbox is unchecked:

[image]

Click “Yes” here:

[image]

-Go to the root server settings and click “FastCGI Settings”:

[image]

-Double click it, then click the “…” for the Environment Variables collection to launch the EnvironmentVariables Collection Editor.

-Set the PYTHONPATH variable:

[image]

-And the WSGI_HANDLER (my Flask app is named hello.py so the value is app.app - if yours is named site.py it would be site.app or similar):

[image]

-Click OK and browse to your site:

[image]

web.conifg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="flasktest" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\virtualenvs\test\Scripts\python.exe|C:\virtualenvs\test\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Did exactly the same thing, but I was looking for a resolution for the issue or error that I have received.

Comment: @RohitVenkatGandhiMendadhala Could you please share what kind of file this is 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\ \Local\\.certifi'? are you using this in your code? try to assign permission to this file.

Comment: The issue was with some libraries inside the code like IPython and requests. Worked after removing them.